# How can I embed the value obtained using innerHTML in Javascript to a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, innerhtml

```
var payamount=document.getElementById("amount").value;
var calamount=payamount*3;
document.getElementById('calculate').innerHTML=calamount;
```

In the Above code the calculated value is diplayed in the text box named calculate but the value is not stored.

Comment: what you want to say by `value is not stored` ? If you wanna store into variable, it's already there in `calamount`

Comment: @TechnoKnol is right; the value *is* stored in `calamount`. What does "value is not stored" mean?

Comment: The value is getting displayed in the screen while using innerHTML but however when the value is displayed in the next page all the values are displayed except that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var payamount=document.getElementById('amount').value;
var calamount=payamount*3;
document.getElementById('calculate').innerHTML=calamount;
```